# iphone cocos2d app and iAd

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, compatibility, iad

I have an iphone 3 device running iOS 3.1.2, I developed a game using cocos2d, i implemented iAd in the lite version (free app), what i did is that i made the iAd framework role "weak" instead of "required", and i made the base SDK iOS 4.2 as it is, and the deployment target iOS 3.1.2.

first problem: i couldnt test the application on my device (iphone 3 - iOS 3.1.2).
Second problem : when the application is submitted to the app store, iphone 4 devices could run it normally and iAd appears, but iphone 3 devices, when getting into the view containing iAd the application hangs and quit.
any help please,
i have been in this problem for a while
regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.  Why could you not test on your device?  What happens when you try to run it on your device?